# Too many TIME_WAIT from 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, linux, symfony

I'm a noob for managing linux server. So if you reply please use simple words.

Since 24H my server is very slow and my CPU is >100%, I'm regularly ddoss attack by script kiddies. So i put this cmd in putty to check if I'm under attack : `netstat -antu | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

An I saw many connections from 127.0.0.1

[image: putty]

After that I put this command : `netstat -np | grep 127.0.0.1`

[image]

You can see there are many TIME_WAIT and I suppose i'ts bad. I'm not sure too read correctly, but all TIME_WAIT come from mysql, no ? I searched on Google but many of replies it's because you don't close mysql after a query. But I'm using Symfony2 with doctrine so I suppose doctrine make a good job and I didn't change a query since 2 weeks.

I've no idea what to do for fixing this problem.

**EDIT** `netstat -nap -A inet`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are all internal connections between your MySQL server and clients running in the same host, via `127.0.0.1`, which is only accessible from inside your host. It isn't any kind of an 'attack by script kiddies', unless you are attacking yourself, or have some malware installed.

Comment: Ok, there is a way to know who make this ?

Answer (score -1):

It seems they're trying to overload your SQL server, this is obviously a DOS attack.
(I guess, as you did not posted the full netstat list, which would show which port the external connections went to ...)
If you're using your SQL database only from localhost, you should configure the SQL server to bind only to localhost

You should follow the details here: [MySQL Listen on localhost only](http://linuxconfig.net/manual-howto/databases/how-to-setup-mysql-listen-on-localhost-only.html)

If this wont solve your problem, but the long list of IP numbers are gone, then you still have some issue with your programs which is accessing the SQL database.

Comment: I've already `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in /etc/my.cnf and restart many time mysql service.

Comment: Please post the output of:

netstat -nap -A inet

Comment: This is only a PART of the netstat, as you can see it have over 4000 connections, which is obviously could not displayed in full ...
Also there's no info on the "LISTENING" part of the netstat, so HOW EXACTLY did you diagnose that the LISTENING is really made only on loopback ?!

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. If it shows `127.0.0.1:3306` it is bound to localhost. Period. Also, he says he 'saw many connections from `127.0.0.1`'. He didn't mention any from anywhere else.

Comment: Yes. THAT specific connection went through "lo".
And what about the other over 4000 ?
"say many from 127.0.0.1" is the main problem, that the local SQL request being delayed.
But this could be caused by malicious activity from an external source!

Comment: I'll say it again. The `netstat` output proves conclusively that the socket concerned is *specifically* listening at `127.0.0.1:3306`. Not at `0.0.0.0:3306`, which is the default, or say `192.168.33.56:3306`, which might be a local IP address. I'll also say again that he 'saw many connections from `127.0.0.1`, and doesn't mention any from anywhere else. They are therefore a figment of your imagination.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the mysql server?
there might be some corrupted tables messing up the system

Comment: Are you running a proxy server on this system? (port 8080)